# Installation of the Windows Phone 7.1 (Beta2)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I was installing the latest WP7 SDK, but it crashes with following error. Any hint what went wrong?

**Error 1935. An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'MSDATASRC, version="7.0.3300.0", publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a", fileVersion="7.0.9466.1", culture="neutral"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070005.**

BR
STeN

Comment: What version of the SDK, if any, did you have installed previously?

Comment: Hi, I have no previous SDK installed. I was thinking that I might be able to install directly the 'Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Beta 2' without having previously installed the 'Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.0' from http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started... This is probably not possible, so I firstly installed the 'Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.0' without any problem and for the time being I skipped installation of the 7.1. I will wait for Mango SDK...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've uninstalled any previous versions of the SDK and make sure you've got all applications (particularly VS) closed.

Failing that, you're better off asking in the [official forums](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/99.aspx).

Comment: Honestly I prefer this forum and I cannot post to the forum you have mentioned until my company is registered on App Hub and since our country is not allowed to register here we cannot use the forum... This is Microsoft policy. We have also problems with phone registrations for development, we have to use UK company for that, which costs 25GBP per remote device registration...

Answer (score 0):

Beside Richard answer, you might to make sure that you have VS2010 SP1 installed in case you have VS2010 (professional or ultimate) Installed on your machine.